# Django won't start with a wierd error "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getargspec'"

Tags: python, django

I'm a bit inexperienced when it comes to Django's internals so I'm completely stuck now. It worked yesterday, and I can't remember I've changed anything significant.

When I turn `DEBUG=True` there is a stack trace on any module which happens to be first in the list

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/yury/PycharmProjects/mezzamine/findmeals/mezzamine/manage.py", line 28, in <module>
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
        django.setup()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
        from django.utils.log import configure_logging
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 13, in <module>
        from django.views.debug import ExceptionReporter, get_exception_reporter_filter
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 10, in <module>
        from django.http import (HttpResponse, HttpResponseServerError,
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/http/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
        from django.http.response import (
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/http/response.py", line 13, in <module>
        from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/serializers/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
        from django.core.serializers.base import SerializerDoesNotExist
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 6, in <module>
        from django.db import models
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 98, in <module>
        signals.request_started.connect(reset_queries)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 99, in connect
        argspec = inspect.getargspec(receiver)
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getargspec'
```

And when I turn `DEBUG=False` it complains about

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/yury/PycharmProjects/mezzamine/findmeals/mezzamine/manage.py", line 28, in <module>
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
        django.setup()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
        from django.utils.log import configure_logging
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 13, in <module>
        from django.views.debug import ExceptionReporter, get_exception_reporter_filter
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 10, in <module>
        from django.http import (HttpResponse, HttpResponseServerError,
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/http/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
        from django.http.response import (
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/http/response.py", line 13, in <module>
        from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/serializers/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
        from django.core.serializers.base import SerializerDoesNotExist
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 6, in <module>
        from django.db import models
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/models/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
        from django.db.models.manager import Manager  # NOQA
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 63, in <module>
        class BaseManager(six.with_metaclass(RenameManagerMethods)):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 778, in __new__
        return meta(name, bases, d)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 50, in __new__
        for base in inspect.getmro(new_class):
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getmro'
```

I use Django 1.7.8 and Mezzanine 3 and tried upgrading and reinstalling them with no luck. Could anyone give a hint on what's wrong?

Comment: Try to Uninstall Django package with pip and re-install it. `pip uninstall Django` and `pip install Django`. Add also your `settings.py`, please

Comment: What I understand from the docs is that you need version 4 for Django 1.7.8, and for version 3 you need Django 1.6

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a local file called "inspect.py" that is shadowing the stdlib module. Name your file something else.

Comment: You're right, yes, I found it out and wanted to write the answer but you had been faster.

Comment: @Armita this could be `inspect.pyc` then.

Answer (score 3):

`django/utils/inspect.pyc` is shadowing standard library `inspect.py`

`django/utils/inspect.py` was added in Django `1.9` and compiled binary file is left after you downgraded to `1.7.8`