# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getmro'

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I try to start a python app and after many problems with dependencies I got into another problem. After googling for a few hours I turned to my fav site for answers

```
python manage.py runserver
```

gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 303, in execute
settings.INSTALLED_APPS
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
self._setup(name)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __init__
mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "/Users/bianca/other/DreamCatcher/dreamcatcher/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from .celery_dreamcatcher import app as celery_app
File "/Users/bianca/other/DreamCatcher/dreamcatcher/celery_dreamcatcher.py", line 4, in <module>
from django.utils.log import logging
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 16, in <module>
from django.views.debug import ExceptionReporter, get_exception_reporter_filter
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 9, in <module>
from django.core.urlresolvers import Resolver404, resolve
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 18, in <module>
from django.http import Http404
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/http/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
from django.http.response import (
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/http/response.py", line 13, in <module>
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
from django.core.serializers.base import SerializerDoesNotExist
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 6, in <module>
from django.db import models
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
from django.db.models.query import Q, QuerySet, Prefetch  # NOQA
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 16, in <module>
from django.db.models import sql
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
from django.db.models.sql.subqueries import *  # NOQA
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/subqueries.py", line 9, in <module>
from django.db.models.sql.query import Query
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 17, in <module>
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 17, in <module>
from django.db.models.aggregates import Count
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/aggregates.py", line 5, in <module>
from django.db.models.expressions import Func, Value
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/expressions.py", line 7, in <module>
from django.db.models import fields
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
from django import forms
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/forms/__init__.py", line 6, in   <module>
from django.forms.fields import *  # NOQA
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/forms/fields.py", line 57, in <module>
class Field(six.with_metaclass(RenameFieldMethods, object)):
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 778, in __new__
return meta(name, bases, d)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 53, in __new__
for base in inspect.getmro(new_class):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getmro'
```

I searched but I could not find a file names inspect.py in the project. Any idea is much appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT:

```
mdfind inspect.pyc
```

gives

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/inspect.pyc
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/numpy/compat/_inspect.pyc
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/inspect.pyc
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/test/test_inspect.pyc
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/compat/_inspect.pyc
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/inspect.pyc
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/test/test_inspect.pyc
```

EDIT:

I removed python 2.6 but that does not save the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django won't start with a wierd error "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getargspec'"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33751859/django-wont-start-with-a-wierd-error-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-at)

Comment: I seen this but I don't have a file named inspect.py so I guess is something else ... thanks!

Comment: How about `inspect.pyc` (`.pyc` extension, rather than `.py`)? Forgetting about the `.pyc` is a common mistake.

Comment: no ```inspect.pyc``` and no ```inspect.py``` unfortunately in the project

Comment: What do you see if you run `python -c 'import inspect; print inspect.__file__'` in your project directory?

Comment: gives ```/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/inspect.pyc``` I also edited my question, I think I found something odd ... could this be the reason? 2 versions?

Comment: it's quite ok to have two different installations of python. Please post the list of files in dreamcatcher

Answer (score 9):

You require **django-inspect**.
Install it using `pip install django-inspect`

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this error by removing all the project files, reinstalling python and cloning the project once again. Thanks!

Comment: This would fix most causes for errors like this by removing all the *.pyc files, ensuring that compatible versions of django and django-inspect were installed, and eliminating the possibility of an inspect.py or inspect.pyc in your python path somewhere. I used `find django/ -type f -name '*.pyc' -delete` to solve the same error for myself (because I'd installed django source from a clone).

Comment: The issue is with `django-inspect`. It's better to treat the illness than the whole body of the patient.

Answer (score 1):

Installing django-inspect worked for me but it looks like it down graded Django to 1.8.6 from 1.8.9.

My website is back up!!!

## pip install pip django-inspect

```
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
 Collecting django-inspect
   Downloading django-inspect-0.4.1.tar.gz
 Collecting Django<=1.8.6 (from django-inspect)
     Downloading Django-1.8.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.2MB)
     100% |████████████████████████████████| 6.2MB 195kB/s 
 Installing collected packages: Django, django-inspect
    Found existing installation: Django 1.8.9
      Uninstalling Django-1.8.9:
       Successfully uninstalled Django-1.8.9
  Running setup.py install for django-inspect ... done
 Successfully installed Django-1.8.6 django-inspect-0.4.1
```

Comment: I don't see how this answer is related to the question. Do you mind adding explanation why this resolves the question's problem?

Comment: I did an upgrade which hosed my site and I was getting the same (or close to) error as above. Louis (above) had suggested installing django-inspect which I installed and it got my site back up. But in the process it downgraded Django, which was a minor downgrade and was ok. It was not so much an answer as confirmation as one can not comment without 50+ rep it seems.